Equivalence of Convex Optimization Problems
I have the following convex program that is derived from the theory of distributionally-robust optimization.
\begin{align*}
&\inf \quad y_0 + \gamma (\rho^2 - \|\hat\mu\|^2 - \mathrm{tr}[\hat\Sigma]) + z + \mathrm{tr}[Z] \\
&\mathrm{s.t.} \quad \gamma \in \mathbb{R}_{+}, y_0 \in\mathbb{R}, y\in\mathbb{R}^{n}, Y\in\mathbb{S}^{n},z\in\mathbb{R}_{+}, Z\in\mathbb{S}_{+}^{n}, \gamma I \succ Y \\
&\qquad \ 
G_1 \triangleq \begin{bmatrix}
\gamma I - Y & y + \gamma \hat\mu \\
(y + \gamma\hat\mu)^\intercal & z
\end{bmatrix} \succeq 0, \quad 
G_2 \triangleq \begin{bmatrix}
\gamma I - Y & \gamma\hat\Sigma^{\frac{1}{2}} \\
\gamma\hat\Sigma^{\frac{1}{2}} & Z
\end{bmatrix} \succeq 0\\
&\qquad \ 
G_3 \triangleq \begin{bmatrix}
Y - Q_j & y - q_j \\
(y - q_j)^\intercal & y_0 - q_j^0
\end{bmatrix} \succeq 0, \quad \forall j = 1,\ldots, J.
\end{align*}
In the above optimization problem, the decision variables are $\{\gamma, y_0, y, Y, z, Z\}$ and the remaining variables are simply constant (user-specified).
What I am interested in is simplifying this semi-definite program (SDP) in the limiting case where $J = 1$ and we just have $Q \triangleq Q_1, q \triangleq q_1$, and $q_j^0 = 0$. In this simple case, the paper I am reading stipulates that we should arrive at the following SDP
\begin{align*}
&\inf \quad y_0 + \gamma (\rho^2 - \|\hat\mu\|^2 - \mathrm{tr}[\hat\Sigma]) + z + \mathrm{tr}[Z] \\
&\mathrm{s.t.} \quad \gamma \in \mathbb{R}_{+}, z\in\mathbb{R}_{+}, Z\in\mathbb{S}_{+}^{n}, \gamma I \succ Q \\
&\qquad \ 
\begin{bmatrix}
\gamma I - Q & y + \gamma \hat\mu \\
(y + \gamma\hat\mu)^\intercal & z
\end{bmatrix} \succeq 0, \quad 
\begin{bmatrix}
\gamma I - Q & \gamma\hat\Sigma^{\frac{1}{2}} \\
\gamma\hat\Sigma^{\frac{1}{2}} & Z
\end{bmatrix} \succeq 0
\end{align*}
This implies that at optimality, we should find that $Y^\star = Q, y^\star = q$, and $y_0^\star = 0$. However, I am having quite a bit of trouble showing this through the KKT conditions. To this end, introducing the (block-matrix) Lagrange multipliers $\Lambda_1, \Lambda_2, \Lambda_3$ corresponding to the LMI constraints $G_1, G_2, G_3$, the Lagrangian becomes
\begin{align}
    L &= y_0 + \gamma(\rho^2 - \|\hat\mu\|^2 - \mathrm{tr}[\hat\Sigma]) + z + \mathrm{tr}[Z] - \langle \Lambda_1, G_1 \rangle - \langle \Lambda_2, G_2 \rangle - \langle \Lambda_3, G_3 \rangle \nonumber \\
    &= y_0 + \gamma(\rho^2 - \|\hat\mu\|^2 - \mathrm{tr}[\hat\Sigma]) + z + \mathrm{tr}[Z] - \mathrm{tr}
    \begin{bmatrix}
        \Lambda_{11} & \Lambda_{12} \\
        \Lambda_{12}^\intercal & \Lambda_{22}
    \end{bmatrix}
    \begin{bmatrix}
        \gamma I - Y & \gamma \hat\Sigma^{\frac{1}{2}} \\
        \gamma \hat\Sigma^{\frac{1}{2}} & Z
    \end{bmatrix} \nonumber \\
    &\hspace{3cm} - \mathrm{tr}
    \begin{bmatrix}
        \bar{\Lambda}_2 & \lambda_2 \\
        \lambda_2^\intercal & \ell_2
    \end{bmatrix}
    \begin{bmatrix}
        \gamma I - Y & \gamma\hat\mu + y \\
        (\gamma\hat\mu + y)^\intercal & z
    \end{bmatrix} - \mathrm{tr}
    \begin{bmatrix}
        \bar{\Lambda}_3 & \lambda_3 \\
        \lambda_3^\intercal & \ell_3
    \end{bmatrix}
    \begin{bmatrix}
        Y - Q & y - q \\
        (y - q)^\intercal & y_0
    \end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
The first-order optimality conditions with respect to the Lagrangian are as follows
\begin{align*}
    (\mathrm{S}1): \frac{\partial L}{\partial y_0} &= 1 - \ell_3 = 0 \implies \boxed{\ell_3 = 1} \\
    (\mathrm{S}2): \frac{\partial L}{\partial z} &= 1 - \ell_2 = 0 \implies \boxed{\ell_2 = 1} \\
    (\mathrm{S}3): \frac{\partial L}{\partial Z} &= I_n - \Lambda_{22} = 0 \implies \boxed{\Lambda_{22} = I_n} \\
    (\mathrm{S}4): \frac{\partial L}{\partial y} &= -2\lambda_2 - 2\lambda_3 = 0 \implies \boxed{\lambda_2 = -\lambda_3} \\
    (\mathrm{S}5): \frac{\partial L}{\partial Y} &= \Lambda_{11} + \bar{\Lambda}_{2} - \bar{\Lambda}_{3} = 0 \implies \boxed{\bar{\Lambda}_{3} = \Lambda_{11} + \bar{\Lambda}_{2}} \\
    (\mathrm{S}6): \frac{\partial L}{\partial\gamma} &= \rho^2 - \|\hat\mu\|^2 - \mathrm{tr}[\hat\Sigma] - \mathrm{tr}[\Lambda_{11} + \bar{\Lambda}_{2} + (\Lambda_{12} + \Lambda_{12}^\intercal)\hat\Sigma^{\frac{1}{2}}] - 2\lambda_2^\intercal\hat\mu = 0 \\
    \implies &\boxed{\mathrm{tr}[\Lambda_{11} + \bar{\Lambda}_{2} + (\Lambda_{12} + \Lambda_{12}^\intercal)\hat\Sigma^{\frac{1}{2}}] + 2\lambda_2^\intercal\hat\mu = \rho^2 - \|\hat\mu\|^2 - \mathrm{tr}[\hat\Sigma]}
\end{align*}
The primal feasibility conditions are
\begin{equation*}
    (\mathrm{P}1): \gamma I - Y \succeq 0, \quad (\mathrm{P}2): Y - Q \succeq 0,
\end{equation*}
and the dual feasibility conditions are
\begin{equation*}
    (\mathrm{D}1): \Lambda_{11} \succeq 0, \quad (\mathrm{D}2): \Lambda_{22} \succeq 0, \quad (\mathrm{D}3): \bar{\Lambda}_2 \succeq 0, \quad (\mathrm{D}4): \ell_2 \succeq 0, \quad (\mathrm{D}5): \bar{\Lambda}_3 \succeq 0, \quad (\mathrm{D}6): \ell_3 \geq 0.
\end{equation*}
The complementary slackness conditions are
\begin{align*}
    &(\mathrm{CS}1): \mathrm{tr}[\Lambda_{11}(\gamma I - Y) + \gamma(\Lambda_{12} + \Lambda_{12}^\intercal)\hat\Sigma^{\frac{1}{2}} + \Lambda_{22}Z] = 0 \\
    &(\mathrm{CS}2): \mathrm{tr}[\bar{\Lambda}_{2}(\gamma I - Y)] + 2\lambda_2^\intercal (\gamma\hat\mu + y) + \ell_2 z = 0 \\
    &(\mathrm{CS}3): \mathrm{tr}[\bar{\Lambda}_{3}(Y - Q)] + 2\lambda_3^\intercal (y - q) + \ell_3 y_0 = 0
\end{align*}
Lastly, we know that $\gamma I - Y \succ 0$ (strict inequality).
Plugging in (S1), (S2), and (S4) into (CS2) and (CS3), and taking the sum gives the constraints
\begin{equation*}
    \mathrm{tr}[\bar{\Lambda}_{2}(\gamma I - Y)] + \mathrm{tr}[\bar{\Lambda}_{3} (Y - Q)] + 2\lambda_2^\intercal(\gamma\hat\mu + q) + z + y_0 = 0.
\end{equation*}
Plugging in all the available information into the block-matrix Lagrange multipliers gives
\begin{equation*}
    \Lambda_1 = 
    \begin{bmatrix}
        \Lambda_{11} & \Lambda_{12} \\
        \Lambda_{12}^\intercal & I_{n}
    \end{bmatrix} \succeq 0, \quad 
    \Lambda_2 = 
    \begin{bmatrix}
        \bar{\Lambda}_{2} & \lambda_2 \\
        \lambda_2^\intercal & 1
    \end{bmatrix} \succeq 0, \quad 
    \Lambda_3 = 
    \begin{bmatrix}
        \Lambda_{11} + \bar{\Lambda}_2 & -\lambda_2 \\
        -\lambda_2^\intercal & 1
    \end{bmatrix} \succeq 0.
\end{equation*}
Using the Schur complement for these three matrices yields the additional constraints
\begin{align*}
    \Lambda_{11} - \Lambda_{12} \Lambda_{12}^\intercal &\succeq 0 \implies \Lambda_{11} \succeq \Lambda_{12} \Lambda_{12}^\intercal, \\
    \bar{\Lambda}_{2} - \lambda_2 \lambda_2^\intercal &\succeq 0 \implies \bar{\Lambda}_{2} \succeq \lambda_2\lambda_2^\intercal, \\
    \Lambda_{11} + \bar{\Lambda}_{2} - \lambda_2 \lambda_2^\intercal &\succeq 0 \implies \Lambda_{11} + \bar{\Lambda}_{2} \succeq \lambda_2\lambda_2^\intercal.
\end{align*}
At this point, I am stuck however, and feel like I have not made much progress in showing that $Y = Q, y = q$, and $y_0 = 0$. The fundamental issue that I am having is that the complementary slackness conditions require the sum of various terms to be zero, and the cross-terms (for example, $2\lambda_3^\intercal (y - q)$) need not be non-negative. If all of the individual terms were required to be be non-negative, then we could make all of the individual terms zero identically, which would significantly simplify everything. As a result, I'm not sure how to proceed. Any help to point me in the right direction would greatly be appreciated!
Source: https://arxiv.org/abs/1908.08729 - Theorem's 14 and 16

Is this term $(\epsilon^2 - |\hat\mu|^2 - \mathrm{tr}[\hat\Sigma])$ always non-negative? How about $Q_1$, PSD? I feel that the result in the paper may not be correct in general. Have you tried some numerical tests?

Why would the term $\epsilon^2 - |\hat\mu|^2 - \mathrm{tr}[\hat\Sigma]$ matter though if it is attached to a linear term that is multiplied by the decision variable $\gamma$? In any case, that term in the objective will be linear. In the paper, they state that $Q$ can be a general symmetric matrix, but for simplicity we can assume its PSD. I'm just trying to figure out how the equivalence stated in the paper is derived, or proved, even with additional assumptions. I can't see how it works out through the KKT conditions

Because you are minimizing that term times $\gamma$, the sign of that term will affect which direction we want push $\gamma$,

I see what you mean. In general, we don't know the sign of this constant because the parameters can be arbitrary :( Based on the necessary conditions though, do you see any way in which we can have $Y^\star = Q, y^\star = q$, and $y_0^\star = 0$ at optimality?
